# RuntimeError: No MovieWriters available in Matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg

The problem I am getting is in code similar to this example: 
https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html

The error:

***RuntimeError: No MovieWriters available*** occurs at `Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']` in the example above.

I am using mac, I have installed ffmpeg using brew, and even installed it with conda even though I am not using anaconda for this particular code.

I am positive that it is installed - I have used it in terminal to change files but it is not working within the program.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to specify path to `ffpmeg` program manually like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

You have to put these code lines at the beginning of a script and then use animation `Writer`.

Comment: By specify path to the program do you mean I should specify the path to the ffmpeg folder or to the unix executable? I've tried both and neither has worked

Comment: Bin means executable

Comment: Ohh thank you so much!! It worked now, the issue was that I needed to put the `plt.rcParams` directly under the `import matplotlib.pyplot` – I don't know why that is though, do you mind explaining that to me?

Comment: RcParams is settings; you have to specify options before using of matplotlib

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why, but in my case here is the one that worked (in my case was on windows).

Initialize a writer:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
Writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30, codec='libx264') # Or 
Writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800) ==> This is WORKED FINE ^_^
```

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg'] ==> GIVES ERROR ""RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available""

Answer (score 0):

I have found '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg' not exists in my computer. so i try this:

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import matplotlib.animation as animation
> Writer = animation.writers['pillow']
> writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
> ```

and it works for me