# Difficulties saving an animation (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ffmpeg

I have a simple animation that I want to save. I followed the example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example_writer.html

But I get the following error: RuntimeError: Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available

I installed ffmpeg and checked via ffmpeg -version that it really is installed and the path correct.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set up formatting for the movie files
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.random.uniform(0,1)
y = np.random.uniform(0,1)


scat = ax.scatter(x,y, color= 'blue')
circle = plt.Circle((x,y), radius=0.1, color='blue', fill=False, lw=0.5)
ax.add_patch(circle)

def init():
    scat = ax.scatter(x, y, color = 'blue')
    circle = plt.Circle((x,y), radius=0.1, color='blue', fill=False, lw=0.5)

def animate(i):
    random = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if random < 0.5:
        scat.set_color('red')
        circle.set_edgecolor('blue')
    else:
        scat.set_color('blue')
        circle.set_edgecolor('red')
    return circle, scat,


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init(), interval=1000, blit=True)
ani.save('test.mp4', writer=writer)
```

None of the proposed solution in [RuntimeError: No MovieWriters available in Matplotlib animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736457/runtimeerror-no-moviewriters-available-in-matplotlib-animation/55754672) worked for me. Any ideas?

Edit: I am using Windows (10)

Comment: It looks like `ffmpeg` in not in the executable path of your Python script. Try to execute `ffmpeg -version` at the beginning of the script: `import subprocess` and `subprocess.run('ffmpeg -version')`. It's also going to help if you post the OS your are using.

Comment: This actually did it. Thank you! (Kinda weird that it does though :D)